# Can I login to my Google Apps mail using my OpenID from myopenid.com?

Tags: gmail, openid

Can I login to my Google Apps mail using my OpenID from myopenid.com? If so, how?

Comment: maybe this answers you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436829/how-do-you-delegate-your-openid-to-google-apps/1204525#1204525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: NO

Google itself is an [OpenID provider nowdays](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/google_is_now_an_openid_provider.php).